# security context in kubernetes deployment

Tags: security, kubernetes

I created a dockerfile which is use user 10001
if it is possible to kubernetes deployment with following security context

```bash
user 10001
```

```yaml
securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
```

Comment: I'd assume this would work; what happens if you try it, and what problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can remote into the container and check with `id` command: `uid=1000 gid=3000 groups=2000`